# C++ typename nested class template

Tags: c++, class, templates, iterator, typename

I came across the following template class to iterate over a binary tree, which has an inner class template for the iterator:

```
template <typename T> struct BinaryTree
{
  Node<T>* root = nullptr;

  explicit BinaryTree(Node<T>* const root)
    : root{ root }, pre_order{ *this }
  {
    root->set_tree(this);
  }

  ~BinaryTree() { if (root) delete root; }

  template <typename U>
  struct PreOrderIterator
  {
    Node<U>* current;

    explicit PreOrderIterator(Node<U>* current)
      : current(current)
    {
    }

    bool operator!=(const PreOrderIterator<U>& other)
    {
      return current != other.current;
    }

    // no continuations in C++ (unlike C#)
    PreOrderIterator<U>& operator++() 
    {
      if (current->right)
      {
        current = current->right;
        while (current->left)
          current = current->left;
      }
      else
      {
        Node<T>* p = current->parent;
        while (p && current == p->right)
        {
          current = p;
          p = p->parent;
        }
        current = p;
      }
      return *this;
    }

    Node<U>& operator*() { return *current; }
  };

  typedef PreOrderIterator<T> iterator;

  iterator end()
  {
    return iterator{ nullptr };
  }

  iterator begin()
  {
    Node<T>* n = root;

    if (n)
      while (n->left)
        n = n->left;
    return iterator{ n };
  }

};
```

But I can't understand why it would be beneficial to create an additional inner class template for the iterator: won't the typename of the iterator always be T, making the additional template redundant ?

Is there some advantage to this approach that I don't get?

Comment: That's some suspect looking code.  What happened when you removed the template from PreOrderIterator?

Comment: I agree: there's no obvious reason for `PreOrderIterator` to be a member template at all.

Comment: @Eljay it still behaves in exactly the same way when I remove the template.